# Iterate over object with Handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to iterate over the email key in this object with handlebars, so only the email values will be presented.

```
 //users object
[{ first_name: 'foo',
last_name: 'foo',
email: 'foo@gmail.com',
phone: '5555' } ]
```

I've tried to use each like this:

```
<ul>
{{#each users}} // iterate over the first array
    {{#each this as |val_user key_user|}} //iterate over the objects

    <li>{{key_user.email}}: {{val_user}}</li> // didn't work
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

**Finale result should be :**

**- email : foo@gmail.com**

I guess i could use an if statement but i think concatenation should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this instead, since you know the `key` to be `email`

```
<ul>
{{#each users}} // iterate over the first array           
    <li>Email: {{this.email}}</li>         
{{/each}}
</ul>
```